# Encoding URL for password reset token

Tags: encoding, asp.net-identity, token

I need to enable user to reset the password on "Page resetting password" and sending via email the link to set up new password.

How do I generate URL for new password setting after generating 'reset token' ?

I cannot pass result of `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user)` directly to URL due to the security settings and I do not want to compromise security by setting this in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

I generate the token usinng `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync` method:

```
string code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally used this code fragment inspired by BlazorHero project:

```
string code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
var route = "set-password";
var origin = "https://localhost:44375"; // FIXME
var endpointUri = new Uri(string.Concat($"{origin}/", route));
var passwordResetURL = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(endpointUri.ToString(), "Token", code);
```

`passwordResetURL` is URL which can be sent via email and opened by the user.